# the number of roots for a non-polynomial continuous function on a closed interval

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a general method to find the number of roots for a non-polynomial 
continuous function on a closed interval?

For example, I know that $\ln^{2}x-\ln x-1/x+1=0$ has only one solution (other than 1) on the interval of $[0,1]$, but how to prove it?

Comment: You can use information about where this function is monotone, and then on each interval use the intermediate value theorem and/or optimization to find the root or show it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think your method will work for the example given above, because monotonicity itself is hard to determine.

Answer (score 0):

**Only few methods**

1. You can sketch a graph if possible, this is most useful.
2. You can use intermediate value theorem.
3. You can also integrate the function and check if $f(b)=f(a)$, then f'(x) will surely have a solution(rolles theorem).

May be there are many others but these are the primary ones.......

Comment: If I understand correctly, rolle's theorem only says there are at least one solution, but not EXACTLY one or at most one, right?

Comment: Yeah as I wrote.."surely a solution" and not one only.

Comment: My question was more about the uniqueness, not the existence, so rolle's theorem won't help, nor will IVT.